# Ruby on Rails NoMethodError in Articles#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I keep getting a no method error. Why? How can I fix this?

NoMethodError in Articles#show
undefined method `photo' for #

I am using ruby on rails and I'm trying to use paperclip so i can upload photos on my app

part of my show file

```
<%= render @article.photos %>  #source of error
<h3>Add a photo:</h3>
<%= render 'photos/form' %>
```

my photos controller

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController

 #Index action, photos gets listed in the order at which they were created
 def index
  @photos = Photo.order('created_at')
 end

 #New action for creating a new photo
 def new
  @photo = Photo.new
 end

 #Create action ensures that submitted photo gets created if it meets the requirements
 def create
  @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
  @photo = @article.photos.create(photo_params)
 redirect_to article_path(@article)


 end

 def destroy
        @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
        @photo = @article.photos.find(params[:id])
        @photo.destroy
        redirect_to article_path(@article)
 end

 private

 #Permitted parameters when creating a photo. This is used for security reasons.
 def photo_params
  params.require(:photo).permit(:title, :image)
 end

end
```

========= UPDATE =======

This is my
articles controller

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
   def new
          @article = Article.new
    end

    def index
     @articles = Article.all
    end

    def show
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    def create
         @article = Article.new(article_params)

        @article.save
        redirect_to @article
    end

    def edit
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
        if @article.update(article_params)
        redirect_to @article
        else
            render 'edit'
        end

    end

    def destroy
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
        @article.destroy

        redirect_to articles_path
    end
end

private
def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
end
```

article model

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :comments
end
```

I fixed it now, but now i have another no method error

undefined method `article_photos_path' for #<#:0x007f17f052d0a0>
Did you mean?  article_path

```
<%= form_for([@article, @article.photos.build]) do |f| %> #source of error
  <div class="form-group">
     <%= f.label :image %>
    <%= f.file_field :image, class: 'form-control'%>
 </div>
    <p>
        <%= f.submit 'Upload Photo' %>
    </p>
    <% end %>
    </p>
    <% end %>
```

Comment: What's in the articles controller?

Comment: just updated the question with it

Comment: How is the articles-photos relation defined? Need to see article model too.

Answer (score 1):

Being Photo another model so, you need to make the proper relationship:

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :comments
  has_many :photos
end

class Photo < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :article
end
```

As I see in your `photo_params`, you don't have the `article_id` attribute then you must add it, running a migration:

```
$ rails g migration add_article_to_photos article:references
$ rails db:migrate
```

After that you should update them:

```
params.require(:photo).permit(:title, :image, :article_id)
```

Comment: You also have to add proper route to config/routes.rb Something like this:
`resources :articles
member do get :photos
end`